# Using "dot" inside a prototype name in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, prototype

Lets say I have this class:

```
function classA(n){
    this.name = n
}

classA.prototype.getName = function(){
    return this.name
}

var x = new classA('john')
console.log(x.getName())
```

My question is: can I group multiple methods inside a namespace? So I would like to do that:

```
var x = new classA('john')
console.log(x.CONSTANT.getName())
```

So I would like to call some methods as x.someMethod() and others as x.CONSTANT.otherMethod()

PS: I'm looking for a cross-browser method. Bind is not working in Safari and IE9.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can do it, for example, via `bind`. Google `es5 shim` for implementation of bind in browsers, which don't support it natively.

```
function MyClass(name) {
   this.name = name;
   this.CONSTANT.otherMethod = this.CONSTANT.otherMethod.bind(this);
}
MyClass.prototype.CONSTANT = {
   otherMethod: function() {
        alert(this.name);
   }
};
```

Comment: I like this approach but I don't like the fact that u need to define all methods inside the CONSTANT json. If you have lots of them the code will have to be indented and everything looks messy. Maybe I could just make otherMethod() inside json to point to the real method defined outside.

Comment: "u need to define all methods inside the CONSTANT json" not obligatory. You may write `MyClass.prototype.CONSTANT = {}; MyClass.prototype.CONSTANT.otherMethod = function(){ ... }`

Comment: thx .... looks clean ... the downside is for ie/safari I need to check for Function.prototype.bind and implement it if it doesn't exist

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know a constant is just a property and it can't contain methods, you need to separate your objects and use methods to have the same effect:

```
function A (id) {

    this.id = id;
    this.showId = function () { return this.id; }
};

function B (a) {

    this.a = a;
    this.getA = function () { return this.a; }
}

var a = new A(12);
var b = new B(a);

b.getA().showId();
```

**edit:**
You can use a literal object as follow

```
function B (id) {

  this.id = id;
  this.CONSTANT = { otherMethod: function () { alert("..."); } };
  someMethod = function () { return this.id; }
}
```

but the literal CONSTANT object can't access B-object methods,

Consider the `@kirilloid` post to round this.

Comment: An object's property can itself be an object that contains methods (and this nesting can go as deep as desired). See the other answers.

Comment: @nnnnnn I updated my answer, anyways I thought literal object was unable to access its parent's methods, turns out you can change this, look kirilloid answer

Comment: Yes, a nested object can't get to its parents automatically through some kind of `parent` property or anything (because in fact nested objects don't actually "belong" to the parent, the parent simply holds a reference to them), but you can work around it with `.bind()`.

Answer (score 0):

You can, but you have to be careful because it won't act like you think it will. The `this` for the method will be the namespace, not the root object.
For example, in `x.CONSTANT.getName()`, the `this` object will be `x.CONSTANT`, and not `x`.

Here's some sample code which kinda does what you ask (or [in jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/HgrZ6/)):

```
function MyClass() {}

MyClass.prototype.CONSTANT = {
    getName: function() {
        alert('Foo');
    }
};


var c = new MyClass();
c.CONSTANT.getName();
```

To make sure the `this` is right, you need to do much more.

Answer (score -1):

You can use getters/setters (read [this article](http://ejohn.org/blog/javascript-getters-and-setters/)) to achieve this. For example you may define it like this:

```
classA.prototype.__defineGetter__('CONSTANT', function() {
    var that = this;
    return {
        getName: function() {
            return that.name;
        }
    };
});
```

Note `that` holding reference to the object. It will work now

```
x = new classA('test');
x.CONSTANT.getName();
// result - test
```